# How to change kernel i/o buffer size

Tags: c, linux, io, linux-kernel

I am running some experiments with I/O intensive applications and am trying to understand the effects of varying the kernel i/o buffer size, different elevator algorithms, and so on.

How can I know the current size of the i/o buffer in the kernel? Does the kernel use more than one buffer as need arises? How can I change the size of this buffer? Is there a config file somewhere that stores this info?

(To be clear, I am not talking about processor or disk caches, I am talking about the buffer used by the kernel internally that buffers reads/writes before flushing them out to disk from time to time).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The kernel does not buffer reads and writes the way you think...  It maintains a "page cache" that holds pages from the disk.  You do not get to manipulate its size (well, not directly, anyway); the kernel will always use *all* available free memory for the page cache.

You need to explain what you are really trying to do.  If you want some control over how much data the kernel pre-fetches from disk, try a search for "linux readahead".  (Hint: `blockdev --setra XXX`)

If you want some control over how long the kernel will hold dirty pages before flushing them to disk, try a search for "linux dirty_ratio".

A specific application can also bypass the page cache completely by using `O_DIRECT`, and it can exercise some control over it using `fsync`, `sync_file_range`, `posix_fadvise`, and `posix_madvise`.  (`O_DIRECT` and `sync_file_range` are Linux-specific; the rest are POSIX.)

You will be able to ask a better question if you first educate yourself about the Linux VM subsystem, especially the page cache.

Answer (score 4):

I think you mean the disk IO queues. For example:

```
$ cat /sys/block/sda/queue/nr_requests
128
```

How this queue is used depends on the IO scheduler that is in use.

```
$ cat /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler
noop anticipatory deadline [cfq]
```

`cfq` is the most common choice, although on systems with advanced disk controllers and in virtual guest systems `noop` is also a very good choice.

There is no config file for this information that I am aware of. On systems that I need to change the queue settings on I put the changes into /etc/rc.local although you could use a full-up init script instead and place it into an RPM or DEB for mass distribution to a lot of systems.

Comment: Thats not exactly what I was looking for, but that helped too.