# disk write buffer size in Linux

Tags: linux

How to find the disk write buffer size in Linux?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/7044958/18157

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change kernel i/o buffer size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044863/how-to-change-kernel-i-o-buffer-size)

Answer (score 2):

`write` system call normally just copies your data to the page cache, which later on gets flushed to the disk. The size of the page cache is dynamic, the kernel tries to use all free memory for it.

See [The Page Cache and Page Writeback](http://sylab-srv.cs.fiu.edu/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=paperclub:lkd3ch16.pdf) for more details.

Comment: In practice, I recommend these days passing a buffer of e.g. 16kbytes to 128kbytes to `write(2)`, benchmark to get the optimal figure (which I believe is not that important!).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I recommend memory mapped files if possible - avoid unnecessary copying.

Answer (score 0):

Data stored in buffer while you copy file for example to USB is in "Dirty" memory.

Try mount your USB flash disk and
#pv file.5GB.. > /media/.../diskname/
it goes quickly and after while hang.. because it fill the buffer in dirty memory

in another terminal
#cat /proc/meminfo | grep Dirty
Dirty memory take a lot of space.
pv raises transfer to 100% and hangs.. Dirty memory take maximum amount and then slowly goes to zero. When it happen, pv ends succesfully.