# What is the advantage of using kernel level buffering for writing files

Tags: caching, io, linux-kernel, block-device

I am currently on optimizing the writing speeds for my application and have the possibility to set the file-system buffersize (kernel level) as well as the buffered i/o buffer size (user level). My problem does only concern writing, there is not one read operation on the drive.

I have read that system calls to kernel space take much time. That would affect the overall writing speed when executing a lot of system calls in a short period of time (e.g. when using small buffers for buffered i/o). Therefore I thought to increase the user-level buffer size for buffered i/o write operations. I am expecting no performance decrease when using just buffered i/o for caching when writing files.

In this context my question raised, what advantage a kernel level buffer would bring to an application that does only write content but never reads anything from the disk...

Answer (score 1):

Caching disk writes has two performance advantages:

1. When writing the same block multiple times, only the final state needs to be written to disk, so earlier writes are avoided.
2. Multiple contiguous writes can be written with a single command, reducing command overhead.

Similarly read cache has two main performance advantages:

1. After reading a block it is kept in cache so a subsequent read of the same block can complete without a disk access.
2. When reading sequential blocks, the system can do a single large read-ahead so that subsequent reads of new blocks will complete without another disk access.

Comment: But what is the difference of using a buffer-mechainism in user- or kernelspace? Is there even a difference? Why then is buffered i/o used so often in combination with a kernel level cache, implemented in the operating system?

Comment: That's to reduce the number of syscalls., which are expensive relative to filling a local buffer.

Comment: This means on the other hand that it's good to just use buffered i/o instead of kernel-level buffering as transferring bigger data blocks from user to kernelspace reduces system calls?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "instead of kernel-level buffering".  There is no either/or here.  When you call setvbuf that's referring to a userspace buffer.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/7044863/1216776